# How to publish Microsoft Teams app for internal company use?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm developing a Microsoft Teams Tab App for internal company use. During development and testing, [side-loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/sideload) works good.

How do I distribute the app and make it available to all Teams and Channels in my tenant?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not yet supported, but we are working on it and hope to have it by early next year.