# Distributing company apps in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

We are looking into the opportunities of apps within Microsoft Teams. We are using Microsoft Teams extensively and believe it can be the application to use as a single entry point to all relevant information. For example, we want to show the internal company news within Teams.

We are currently envisioning what the preferred way for us would be, based on O365. There are however a number of challenges we currently face with Microsoft Teams and wonder if there is a solution for these or if there are items on the roadmap that can help in this scenario:

1. **Show the app on the left menu bar**
   Currently personal apps can be added on the left navigation bar. We
   would like to add a button which is not hidden behind the ellipsis
   but right on the menu bar itself. If possible even change the order.
   Will this be a possibility or will the apps remain behind the
   ellipses?
2. **Deploy the app within the company only** We would like to create company specific apps which work with company data. 
   We can create apps like this, but from a deployment view, we can only use side loading or the online store. For company specific apps this will not be a valid option (5000+ users). Will this become available?
3. **Automatically deploy the “personal app” for all users**
   When deploying an app to the left bar, it is considered a personal app. Will it be possible to provision this app for all users within the company?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to publish Microsoft Teams app for internal company use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46787635/how-to-publish-microsoft-teams-app-for-internal-company-use)

Answer (score 2):

All three of these are on the roadmap, with item 2 ([duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46787635/how-to-publish-microsoft-teams-app-for-internal-company-use)) being the first one likely to appear in the first quarter of calendar 2018.

Comment: Thanks! Have to wait then.